# Getting request body, url from HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler

Tags: java, rest, spring-integration

Is there any way to get request body and url (for log at level info) from HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler before executing request?

Answer (score 0):

There is a code like `org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor` in the:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Created " + method.name() + " request for \"" + url + "\"");
}
```

So, turning on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.http.client.support` you can see the URL in the logs.

The body you can see via debug message in the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`:

```
logger.debug("Writing [" + requestBody + "] using [" + messageConverter + "]");
```